# Excel VBA program errors out on single digit strings in the third case passed into the method

Tags: excel, vba

I am stumped on an error in my excel program that fails to process singular digits in case 3 in my switch statement.  I pass in number sequences from an excel worksheet cell and the program sorts the numbers out and will eventually do stuff assuming I can get the program to read case 3 singular digits and write the string like the double digits in case 3 do.  I will attach the program with comments.  Everything works fine, except when passing in a singular digit in a number sequence in the third case, like "0_1_2", 2 being the third case.  "0_1_20" will work, however.  A series of numbers, "0_1_10, 0_1_11, 0_1_12" also works as intended, but will error if any third number in a sequence is singular.

```
Sub ProcessLinks(ByVal x As String)
'A sub that requires a string from an excel cell in a spreadsheet
Dim a, b, c, count As Integer
'create a, b, and c integers to temporarily hold numerals for export
count = 1
'create a counter variable and set it to equal 1
Dim strnum As String
strnum = ""
'create a blank string
For iCnt = 1 To Len(x)
    'For loop that cycles through the string passed into the sub
    On Error GoTo ErrHandler:
    'error handler
    If IsNumeric(Mid(x, iCnt, 1)) = True Then
        'if the current character in the loop is true, then continue processing
        Select Case count
            'a switch statement that monitors the count variable
            Case 1
                'if count is one switch
                MsgBox ("c" & count)
                a = Mid(x, iCnt, 1)
                'a interger is equal to the current number character in the loop.  It's always singular and followed by a _ character
                MsgBox (a)
                strnum = strnum & Mid(x, iCnt, 1) & "_"
                'set the blank strnum string variable to be equal to the current character and concatenate _ next to it
                count = count + 1
                'add 1 to the counter so the next number in the string will trigger Case 2
            Case 2
                MsgBox ("c" & count)
                b = Mid(x, iCnt, 1)
                'set b interger to be equal to the current number selected in the loop.
                MsgBox (b)
                strnum = strnum & Mid(x, iCnt, 1) & "_"
                'just like a, b is always a singular number followed by the _ character
                count = count + 1
                'add 1 to the counter so the next number in the string will trigger Case 3
            Case 3
                MsgBox ("c" & count)
                MsgBox (iCnt)
                     If IsNumeric(Mid(x, iCnt + 1, 1)) And iCnt + 1 = Len(x) Then
                     'Checks if the number given is followed by another number, thus, a double digit, and also makes sure that the number following this number is the last character in the string, thus, the double digit number is last, so we need to concatenate properly.
                        MsgBox (iCnt + 1 & " " & Len(x))
                        MsgBox ("iCnt + 1 is numeric and last number in cell")
                        strnum = strnum & Mid(x, iCnt, 1)
                        strnum = strnum & Mid(x, iCnt + 1, 1)
                        'these two above lines concatenate the string again and make the double digit number
                        c = Mid(x, iCnt, 1) & Mid(x, iCnt + 1, 1)
                        'this line concatenates the last two digits in the string and makes c equal the final double digit
                        'iCnt = iCnt + 1
                        MsgBox (c)
                        MsgBox ("case3: " & strnum)
                        Exit For
                        'Since this is the final number, we can exit the loop because we don't need any more information
                        'NOTE: This code segment is working fine.
                     ElseIf IsNumeric(Mid(x, iCnt + 1, 1) And iCnt + 1 < Len(x)) Then
                        'This also checks for a double digit, but if the number following the given number isn't the last number in the x string, we will handle it here.
                        MsgBox ("iCnt + 1 is numeric but not last number in cell")
                        strnum = strnum & Mid(x, iCnt, 1)
                        strnum = strnum & Mid(x, iCnt + 1, 1) & ","
                        'concatenating the strnum string with the two numbers in the x string listed in the above 2 lines.
                        c = Mid(x, iCnt, 1) & Mid(x, iCnt + 1, 1)
                        'creating the double digit for my c interger
                        iCnt = iCnt + 1
                        'since I am looking forward in the iCnt For loop counter to make the double digit, and I need to continue to the next string, I will add 1 to iCnt before Next iCnt does.
                        MsgBox (c)
                        'NOTE: The above code segment was working fine with the above If statement.  strings like "1_3_14, 1_5_11" or "2_3_18" were processing correctly
                     ElseIf iCnt = Len(x) Then
                        'Double digit numbers would not make it this far, a singular third number that is last in the x string should trigger this condition
                        MsgBox ("singular number is last")
                        c = Mid(x, iCnt, 1)
                        'storing the third singular number as c interger
                        MsgBox (c)
                        strnum = strnum & Mid(x, iCnt, 1)
                        'storing the completed number series into strnum
                        MsgBox ("case3: " & strnum)
                        Exit For
                     Else
                        'double digit numbers will not make it this far, and a singular number that is last should have been picked up by now.
                        'this statement handles all singular numbers from the x string here
                        MsgBox ("regular singular number")
                        c = Mid(x, iCnt, 1)
                        'stores the c int
                        MsgBox (c)
                        strnum = strnum & Mid(x, iCnt, 1) & ", "
                        'completes the number series and concatenates a ", " to it so another number series can be added dynamically later
                     End If
                MsgBox ("case3: " & strnum)
                'export strnum (unwritten code segment)
                'export a,b,c (unwritten code segment)
                count = 1
                'still in case3, since we are done with the counter, reseting it to 1 for the next number series
                strnum = ""
                'reseting the strnum string so I can build another number sequence
        End Select
    End If
Next iCnt
Exit Sub
ErrHandler:
MsgBox ("error")
End Sub

'Problems: in case 3, singular digits error out for some reason.  Double digits are handled perfectly.
'MsgBox statements do not launch from the last two IF conditions, there is just an error no matter what.
```

'GOAL: get a number sequence with a singular digit in the third case to register and complete the number sequence just like a double digit does.
'RULES: 
'Each string in the cell is comma delimited followed by white space.
'The last string in the cell is not comma delimited, the string ends on a number
'each string contains three numbers, a single digit followed by a "*", then another single followed by a "*", then a single or double digit number.
'example acceptable numbers: 0_1_2, 1_5_0, 2_6_14, 0_1_11

'Project operation: This program will read an excel spreadsheet with drive numbers bus_enclosure_drive, and export the numbers into an array.
'It will also check another sheet for the drive types by identifying the row ID number the drive is on.  This is an ease of access program
'that aides navigating a huge spreadsheet without investing in expensive software.

Comment: Unclear............what is a typical input and expected output.

Comment: I'm currently testing this code segment.  Expected output would be a message box from case 3 stating c3 followed by the singular digit number in a msgbox.  "0_1_2" should message "c1, 0, c2, 1, c3, 2, 0_1_2", but currently messages out "c1, 0, c2, 1, c3" then errors out on 2.  The program handles long strings like "0_1_11, 1_1_12, 1_2_13" just fine.  It will error on "0_1_11, 1_1_1, 0_1_12" because 1_1_1 has a third digit that is singular.

Comment: Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
ProcessLinks (Target.Value)
End Sub

Comment: the above code should allow you to inject strings from your spreadsheet

Comment: I also added a few msgboxes that count cInt in case 3, so you may want to omit those.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Split()

It appears you are writing an algorithm that would accomplish the same thing as an intrinsic VBA method.

`Split()` is a string parsing method that splits a string into an Array. Also, if your algorithm needs to return the result to the calling subroutine it must be declared as a function with a return value. The example below uses `", "` as the delimiter:

```
Function ProcessLinks(ByVal x As String) As Variant
     Dim sArr as Variant
     sArr = Split(x, ", ")
     ProcessLinks = sArr
End Function
```

For example it would split "0_1_2, 1_5_0, 2_6_14, 0_1_11" into this array:

```
sArr(0) = "0_1_2"
sArr(1) = "1_5_0"
sArr(2) = "2_6_14"
sArr(3) = "0_1_11"
```

You can then split the results into an Array using `"_"` as the delimiter:

```
Dim sSubArray as Variant
sSubArray = Split(sArr(2),"_") 'using index 3 as an example
```

Becomes this array:

```
sSubArray(0) = "2"
sSubArray(1) = "6"
sSubArray(2) = "14"
```

---

### RE: Your code

The error came from a misplaced parenthesis, this code executes:

```
Sub ProcessLinks(ByVal x As String)
    Dim a, b, c, count As Integer
    count = 1
    Dim strnum As String
    strnum = ""
    For iCnt = 1 To Len(x)
        If IsNumeric(Mid(x, iCnt, 1)) = True Then
            Select Case count
                Case 1
                    a = Mid(x, iCnt, 1)
                    strnum = strnum & Mid(x, iCnt, 1) & "_"
                    count = count + 1
                Case 2
                    b = Mid(x, iCnt, 1)
                    strnum = strnum & Mid(x, iCnt, 1) & "_"
                    count = count + 1
                Case 3
                    If IsNumeric(Mid(x, iCnt + 1, 1)) And iCnt + 1 = Len(x) Then
                       strnum = strnum & Mid(x, iCnt, 1)
                       strnum = strnum & Mid(x, iCnt + 1, 1)
                       c = Mid(x, iCnt, 1) & Mid(x, iCnt + 1, 1)
                       Exit For
                    ElseIf IsNumeric(Mid(x, iCnt + 1, 1)) And iCnt + 1 < Len(x) Then
                       strnum = strnum & Mid(x, iCnt, 1)
                       strnum = strnum & Mid(x, iCnt + 1, 1) & ","
                       c = Mid(x, iCnt, 1) & Mid(x, iCnt + 1, 1)
                       iCnt = iCnt + 1
                    ElseIf iCnt = Len(x) Then
                       c = Mid(x, iCnt, 1)
                       strnum = strnum & Mid(x, iCnt, 1)
                       Exit For
                    Else
                       c = Mid(x, iCnt, 1)
                       strnum = strnum & Mid(x, iCnt, 1) & ", "
                    End If
                    MsgBox ("case3: " & strnum)
                    count = 1
                    strnum = ""
            End Select
        End If
    Next iCnt
End Sub
```

This:

```
ElseIf IsNumeric(Mid(x, iCnt + 1, 1) And iCnt + 1 < Len(x)) Then
```

Was changed to this:

```
ElseIf IsNumeric(Mid(x, iCnt + 1, 1)) And iCnt + 1 < Len(x) Then
```

The error was "Type mismatch". It helps to disable your error handler so you can actually see what error code you are getting to know how to fix it. In this case you were passing a Boolean value to the `IsNumeric()` method instead of a String.

---

### Your Code Simplified:

This will yield the exact same result less the trailing ",":

```
Function SimplifiedProcessLinks(ByVal x As String) As Variant
    Dim sArr As Variant
    Dim i As Integer
    sArr = Split(x, ", ")
    For i = 0 To UBound(sArr)
        MsgBox sArr(i)
    Next i
End Function
```

Comment: thanks for the tip.  this should allow me to do away with the whole program I just wrote.  However, I would still like to know why singular digits crash the program in case 3.

Comment: I'm not changing iCnt, or I'm not trying to.  The condition looks ahead and checks if the next string is also a number, thus, it is detecting If the number is a double digit number.  Then it checks if that next string is the last one in the cell.  If it isn't, ElseIf to the next condition, double digit but has a string after it.  If that is false, my intention is that the iCnt, the current number, not + 1, gets checked if it is the last singular number in the cell.  If that is false, Else write a number with a , space because there is no possible other condition in my program I want to handle.

Comment: If I am somehow changing iCnt, then maybe it is the iCnt + 1 = Len(x)?

Comment: My bad... I finally executed your code instead of making some assumptions while trying to follow the logic in the code. I've revised the answer.

Comment: you rock!  syntax subtleties are murder sometimes.

Comment: Note that `Split` returns a 0 based array.  All the above code neds to be adjusted for this.

Comment: @chrisneilsen Thanks for pointing that out, answer is revised.